# Laravel 5 Relationship Not Working?

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-5

In my app I have few models: User and Profile. The User model is only for companies, my app is for companies only. When a user registers, they only fill in their name, email address and password. My Profile model has columns for company name, address etc. My profile form does not work; not saving to the database. Here is the setup:

**Controller for the form:**

```
public function update($company_name)
{
  $user = User::whereCompanyName($company_name)->firstOrFail();

      $user->fill(Input::all());

      $user->save();

      flash('You have successfully edited your profile');

      return redirect('/');
}
```

**User.php:**

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Profile');
}
```

**Profile.php:**

```
protected $fillable = ['company_name', 'company_logo', 'company_founded'];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id','ID');
}
```

**The Form:**

```
{!! Form::model($user, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('profile.update', $user->company_name), 'files' => true)) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('user_id', Auth::user()->id) !!}

    // more fields

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('company_name', 'Company Name') !!}
    {!! Form::text('company_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
 </div>

{!! Form::submit('Update Profile', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Have I set the relationship correct? Nothing is saving to the database.

Comment: Provide us some code from your controller.

Comment: @mininoz just realised. It's updated

Comment: Also don't forget to change `profile()` within User.php: `return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re updating the user model and the user model only. You need to also set the attributes in the `profile` relation:

```
$user->update(Input::all());
$user->profile->update(Input::all());
```

Your controller action could also be tidied up a bit, by using [route–model binding](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding) to inject your `User` model instance, and also use the service container to provide a `Request` instance too so you’re not using the `Input` façade:

```
public function update(User $user, Request $request)
{
    $user->update($request->all());
    $user->profile->update($request->all());

    flash('You have successfully updated your profile.');

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: I like your way. I'll try it with my next controller.

Comment: Im getting `'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: _method'`

Comment: @Sylar My guess is - since you're doing `Input::all()` Laravel attempts to update a column corresponding to the hidden field in the form called `_method`. Use `Input::except()` instead, and pass an array of all form input names that should _not_ be updated. Or you could also use `Input::only()` and specify the input names that _must_ be taken when updating.

Comment: @Sylar That shouldn’t happen if you’re using a model. Laravel will only try and fill attributes declared in the `$fillable` property when passing an array to `update()`.

Comment: But where do I put: `$user->update(Input::all());
$user->profile->update(Input::all());`

Comment: @Sylar Your controller action.

Comment: I have come to this. You must be correct as you are well experienced and I must thank you but maybe there is an issue in my code as Im still getting the `_method` issue. I may just add the company details to the user's table and call it a day.

Comment: @Sylar Can you post the code in your controller action exactly as is?

Comment: @MartinBean I have added those columns to the users table. Im tired lol

Answer (score 0):

I want to comment but do not have enough reputation :( A few days ago I found a little problem with this approach:

```
$user->update(Input::all());
$user->profile->update(Input::all());
```

In this case the **mutators** in related model (profile in the example) like this are not invoked (may be a bug):

```
public function setLoremIpsumAttribute($attr)
{
    # code
}
```

In **controller** I tried another approach and it worked:

```
$user->update($request->all());
$user->profile->fill($request->all()['profile'])->push();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 when you want to chain with relation, you need for exemple (Post with comment related) use the method from your comment.

```
Post::find(id)->comment()->where(your where statement)
```

Docs from Laravel:

If you need to add further constraints to which comments are retrieved, you may call the comments method and continue chaining conditions:

```
$comments = Post::find(1)->comments()->where('title', '=', 'foo')->first();
```